# Skiasharp Canvas does not appear in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am following this example here . 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/arcs

More specifically the Exploded pie chart with example code here :
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/Curves/ExplodedPieChartPage.cs

My issue is here :

```
    SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
    canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
    Content = canvasView;
```

It works fine and it display the circle but I do not want the canvasView to be the entire content of a page .

I tried to add this line in my xaml but when I use it it does not display the circle .

```
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView " PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"/>
```

it looks like it only works if i defined SKCanvasView in my C# code and assigned it to a page content .but my design have more objects inside the view other than the drawings (buttons and labels).

I also tried this and it did not work .

```
stacklayout.Children.Add(canvasView);
```

Comment: specify a Height and Width for the SKCanvasView

Comment: @Jason it worked . thanks

Comment: by any chance would you know how to make the circle spin ? like the wheel of fortune game ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/animation

Comment: I found this tutorial much better for rotating https://trailheadtechnology.com/rotate-everything-with-skiasharp-and-xamarin/